# showing that the maximum distance between any pair of points inside a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, pigeonhole-principle

Hello i was looking through problems and found this one which i thought was quite challenging and i still haven't managed to find a solution. anyway here is the problem.

Given $541$ points in the interior of a circle of unit radius, show that there must be a subset of $10$ points whose diameter (the maximum distance between any pair of points) is less than $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$.

Comment: This type of problem is usually solved using pigeonhole principle. Do you know it ? See an example of application in (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2054210)

Comment: i've not seen this before thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Superimpose a $\frac14$ unit by $\frac14$ unit grid over the circle with one of the grid points falling on the center of the circle.  You should be able to show that the circle is covered by $60$ grid squares.

Then as suggested by JeanMarie in a comment, apply the Pigeonhole Principle.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle